# XBMC/Kodi Default Volume

Tags: linux, audio, kodi

Kodi (formerly XBMC) seems to use a global setting for volume level, so when it goes to the next episode, it stops using whatever I've recently adjusted it to and goes back to the default volume level. To me, this is unexpected and undesirable behavior. Every media playing device I've ever used maintains the volume level you've most recently set when advancing to the next episode/song/track/whatever. Is there any way to make Kodi behave normally and use the volume level I last set rather than the default one when advancing to the next episode?

Note: I understand I can change the default volume, but that is not desirable, I'd have to change the default everytime I adjust the volume.

Comment: Hopefully this question makes sense. I've tried to explain it the best I possibly can. If it does not, please don't vote it down, just tell me what you don't understand I will re-word the question.

Comment: *"Is there any way to make Kodi behave normally ..."* -- It's open source.  Change the code and build a custom version for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Open video, select **Settings**, then **Audio and subtitle settings**, adjust Volume and check **Set as default for all media**.